# Including Large Binary Blobs in Python Files

Tags: python, file, rsa

What's the best practice if one wants to include large binary blobs into a single python file?

The blobs are essentially concentrated RSA-4096 public keys encoded in base64 and delimited (about 3,000 of them).

I have no other option than including them in a single file (employer orders).

Comment: If they're already base64 encoded, can't you just include them in a (byte)string literal?

Comment: @delnan That was my first though, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way. I realize that my options are rather limited.

Comment: Is there any way to place the blob in an external file, use a function to fetch it in the `.py` file, but somehow have it fully included when compiled to a `.pyc` file?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying a cPickle?

http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html

Have a simple function/module load the data into a cPickle then operate on the cPickle directly.

Comment: Since `pickle` creates blobs, you still have the problem of embedding a blob in the module. Well, protocol version 0 isn't a blob, but I doubt it'll be more space efficient than base64.

Comment: @delan I agree about the pickle not resolving the embedding.  I don't know of a way to embed specific values without hardcoding.  I think the best Chris can do is ship the data with the module.  Using a pickle retains the structure, but a CSV file might work just as well since it's just a sequence of keys.